# Vertical alignment of y-axis ticks on Seaborn heatmap

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap

I'm plotting a `Seaborn heatmap` and I want to center the `y-axis` tick labels, but can't find a way to do this. `'va'` text property doesn't seem to be available on `yticks()`.

Considering the following **image**

[image]
I'd like to align the days of the week to the center of the row of squares

**Code** to generate this graph:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Generate dummy data
startDate = '2017-11-25'
dateList = pd.date_range(startDate, periods=365).tolist()
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': dateList,
                'Distance': np.random.normal(loc=15, scale=15, size=(365,))
              })
#set week and day
df['Week'] = [x.isocalendar()[1] for x in df['Date']]
df['Day'] = [x.isocalendar()[2] for x in df['Date']]

#create dataset for heatmap
#group by axis to plot
df = df.groupby(['Week','Day']).sum().reset_index()
#restructure for heatmap
data = df.pivot("Day","Week","Distance")

#configure the heatmap plot
sns.set()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,6))
ax=sns.heatmap(data,xticklabels=1,ax = ax, robust=True, square=True,cmap='RdBu_r',cbar_kws={"shrink":.3, "label": "Distance (KM)"})
ax.set_title('Running distance', fontsize=16, fontdict={})

#configure the x and y ticks
plt.xticks(fontsize="9")
plt.yticks(np.arange(7),('Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun'), rotation=0, fontsize="10", va="center")

#set labelsize of the colorbar
cbar = ax.collections[0].colorbar
cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=10)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Adding `+0.5` to `np.arange(7)` in the `plt.yticks()` worked for me

```
plt.yticks(np.arange(7)+0.5,('Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun'),
           rotation=0, fontsize="10", va="center")
```

Answer (score 8):

onno's solution works for this specific case (matrix-type plots typically have labels in the middle of the patches), but also consider these more general ways to help you out:

a) find out where the ticks are first

```
pos, textvals = plt.yticks()
print(pos)

>>> [0.5 1.5 2.5 3.5 4.5 5.5 6.5]
```

and of course you can use these positions directly during the update:

```
plt.yticks(pos,('Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun'), 
    rotation=0, fontsize="10", va="center")
```

b) use the object-based API to adjust only the text

the pyplot commands `xticks` & `yticks` update both the positions and the text at once.  But the axes object has independent methods for the positions (`ax.set_yticks(pos)`) and for the text (`ax.set_yticklabels(labels)`).

So long as you know how many labels to produce (and their order), you need not even think about their positions to update the text.

```
ax.set_yticklabels(('Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun'), 
    rotation=0, fontsize="10", va="center")
```

Answer (score 6):

This is an old question, but I recently had this issue and found this worked for me:

```
g = sns.heatmap(df)
g.set_yticklabels(labels=g.get_yticklabels(), va='center')
```

and of course you can just define `labels=myLabelList` also, as done in the OP